# Advanced TFS 2013 install pointing to TFS 2010 database

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm in the middle of what Microsoft calls an advanced TFS 2013 installation on new hardware.  I want to point it at my current database running TFS 2010 on a different server and wanted to know if I can do this or if there are any tools available to upgrade the existing database.

I upgraded the SQL Server running the TFS2010 databases to SQL Server 2012 and can connect so that is not an issue.  I'd like to keep the same databases for obvious reasons and could not find any info on a road map to do so.

Anybody have any insight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes in here and is looking for an answer.  It is possible to install TFS2013 on one box and point to databases that were created in TFS2010, but those databases must be converted to SQL Server 2012.

What I did was to upgrade our SQL Server from 2008 to 2012 and the tfs databases were still accessible to users on tfs 2010.  Then you go to the tfs 2013 administrator and attach a collection.  You put your server name into the available servers edit control and you'll see your project collection database.  The first part of the attach process is an evaluation and if something bad happens, at least it's in the analysis phase.  Make sure you have a database backup and then click through so that the operation starts.

After the database is attached through tfs, you have some work in sql server to do.  First detach the collection in tfs 2013.  Then, in sql server, backup the project collection database again and copy it to your new tfs 2013 server running sql server.  Then, again in sql server, detach the database.

Then go back to tfs 2013 and in sql server restore from the backup you created.  Once that is done, in the tfs 2013 interface attach the collection and you're good to go.

Hope this helps.